# Having trouble in Session management

Tags: java, android, session, sharedpreferences, session-management

i m working on an application and i want to make user login only when he/she logouts his previous session but i m unable to do it. whenever i close my program and re-open it. it directs to Homepage again even if i had'nt logout. plz

```
  package in.co.medimap.www.medimap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static in.co.medimap.www.medimap.R.layout.login;

/**
 * Created by sony on 28-04-2016.
 */
public class login extends Activity {
TextView signup_text;
Button login_button;
EditText PHONE_NO,PASSWORD;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
public static final String MyPREFERENCE ="Myprefs";
public static final String PHONE="phone";
public static final String PASS="password";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);



    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    signup_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    signup_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           startActivity(new Intent(login.this,register.class));
                                       }
                                   });
    PHONE_NO=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    PASSWORD=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String ph = PHONE_NO.getText().toString();
            String p=PASSWORD.getText().toString();


            if (ph.equals("")||p.equals("")) {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong...");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill all the fields...");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else
            {
  //see from here
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(PHONE, ph);
                editor.putString(PASS, p);
                editor.commit();

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(login.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("login",ph,p);

            }







}
});
    }
}
```

this is my homeactivity where after logging user goes
and i want that if i hadn't logout then whenever i open my app it should start from here

```
package in.co.medimap.www.medimap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

Button Logout = null;

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Logout);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txt);
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    textView.setText(message);

    Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(login.MyPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });




}
}
```

Comment: you description is not very clear. please read your question again and try to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want logout to happen each time user leaves the application, why don't you just do it manually?

you've already set Logout buttons `setOnClickListener` so just do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(Logout != null) {
        Logout.callOnClick();
    }
}
```

This means every time user leaves this activity it will logout.
make sure you handle cases where if they leave activity but go to a different activity on your page, it doesn't log out.

=========== EDIT ===========

I'm guessing your `login` activity is the main activity that starts when application opens so just put this in `onCreate` before you perform any other tasks.  right after `setContentView`, you should do this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(login.MyPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String phone = sharedPreferences.getString(PHONE, "");
String pass = sharedPreferences.getString(PASS, "");

if(!phone.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()) {
    // this means ID and passwords are already saved so just start your home activity here
    startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

In your `MainActivity`:

Just read the values from `SharedPreferences` and login if you have to.

Hope this helps.

========== EDIT 2

Also, your Logout should look like this. Don't use `commmit` or `clear`. put empty values and use `apply`

```
Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(login.MyPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PHONE, "");
        editor.putString(PASS, "");
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want user dont have to login every time he/ she open my app unless he/she logout it ....

Comment: OH! ok now i understand your question. give me one min. I will fix my answer

Comment: one more edit. When they logout, clear the `SharedPreferences` values so when they come back, it values are empty and it won't try to login automatically

Comment: login activity is not my launching activity. launching activity is splash screen

Comment: So you should do that "edit 2" in splash screen. If `SharedPreference` values are empty, launch login activity. if the values exist, that means user didn't logout so launch your home activity